# Refresh [account:one-time-login-url]

Tags: tokens, users

I have a module that creates a new user and automatically logs

```
//set up the user fields
$fields = array(
  'name' => $login,
  'mail' => $to_insert['email'],
  'pass' => user_password(10),
  'status' => 1,
  'init' => $to_insert['email'],
  'timezone' => 'Europe/Paris',
  'roles' => array(
     DRUPAL_AUTHENTICATED_RID => 'authenticated user',
  ),
);

//the first parameter is left blank so a new user is created
$user = user_save('', $fields);
user_login_finalize();
```

However, I want to create a rule to send the information to the new user.
I would use the token **[account: one-time-login-url]** but it does not work.

What for?
How to refresh this token when I create a new user?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

You can handle this very easily in your module. Once you save the account and you have the user object just simply use [_user_mail_notify()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/_user_mail_notify/7). As an example:

```
 _user_mail_notify('password_reset', $account);
```

If you want to alter the email in any way you can do that with [hook_mail_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_mail_alter/7) from within your custom module.

Answer (score 0):

The *one time login URL* token is a special token because it is not implemented by any `hook_tokens()`. This means that in the list of the tokens implemented by a module, you will never find that token.
It is a token that is expressly generated when some emails are sent to the users, such as:

- register_no_approval_require
  The users registered an account, and they don't need any approval
- register_admin_created
  An admin user created an account
- password_reset
  A user asked for a password reset
- status_activated
  An account has been activated

From the code you are showing, it seems it's an administrator user creating accounts through your module. In that case, I would use the *register_admin_created* email, that could be sent using the following code.

```
$params['account'] = $user;
$language = user_preferred_language($user);
$mail = drupal_mail('user', 'register_admin_created', $user->mail, $language, $params);
```

The `$user` variable is the same variable you have.